# Routing issues with javascriptspellcheck and asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spell-checking

I want to implement the [**javascriptspellcheck**](http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/) (A javascript + .net spellchacker plugin ) in my asp.net mvc application, the standalone example works fine but when I am trying to implement it in my application, the **include.js** causes routing issues.

I have no idea, how to overcome from this, your help will get me relief.

**The suggestions are also invited for asp.net mvc spellchecker**

Comment: In order for any of us to help you we need to know what your code/setup looks like and what exact problems are you facing. As it stands, your question is very vague and impossible to answer.

Comment: The plugin provides the setup that I just want to configure in my asp.net mvc application, I follows the steps as provided in the plugin guideline but there is no proper guideline for MVC application and no custom code is needed, It is just a configuration